# Index 0 out of Range en un Recycler View, Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo las siguientes data class, las cuales me sirven para crear un dia en mi app, asi como cargarlo y guardarlo

```
data class Meal(
    val name: String = "",
    var calories: Int = 0,
    var protein: Int = 0,
    var sodium: Int = 0,
    var carbs: Int = 0,
    var fiber: Int = 0,
    var sugar: Int = 0,
    var fats: Int = 0,
    var sFats: Int = 0,
    var tFats: Int = 0,
    var products: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf()
) {
    companion object {
        val mealNamesMap = mapOf(
            "MealOne" to 0,
            "MealTwo" to 1,
            "MealThree" to 2,
            "MealFour" to 3,
            "MealFive" to 4,
            "MealSix" to 5
        )
    }
}

data class Day(
    val date: String,
    var water: Water = Water(),
    val meals: List<Meal> = List(6) { Meal() }
)

object StorageDayUtils {
    var currentDate: String = "" // Variable global para almacenar la fecha del día

    fun saveDay(day: Day, context: Context, load: Boolean) {
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(day)
        val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("storage_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putString(day.date, json)
        editor.apply()

        if (load){
            loadDay(day.date, context)
        }
    }

    fun loadDay(date: String, context: Context): Day? {
        val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("storage_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val json = sharedPreferences.getString(date, null)
        val day = Gson().fromJson(json, Day::class.java)

        day?.let {
            FunctionsDay.updateMealTextViews(it)
            FunctionsDay.updateListView(it)
            FunctionsDay.updateWaterGlasses(it)
        }

        return day
    }

    fun returnDay(date: String, context: Context): Day? {
        val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("storage_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val json = sharedPreferences.getString(date, null)
        return Gson().fromJson(json, Day::class.java)
    }

    fun checkAndCreateNewDayIfNecessary(context: Context, date: String = FragmentUtils.getCurrentDate()) {
        val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("storage_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        if (!sharedPreferences.contains(date)) {
            val newDay = Day(date = date)
            currentDate = date
            saveDay(newDay, context, true)
        } else {
            loadDay(date, context)
            currentDate = date
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora, dentro de otro fragmento, con el siguiente botón, agrego cualquier alimento, a la comida deseada y obtenida mediante otro botón, despues de eso, guardo el dia

```
bttAddFood.setOnClickListener {
            val selectedMeal = FunctionsDay.getSelectedMeals()
            selectedMeal.let { mealVar ->
                val mealIndex = Meal.mealNamesMap[mealVar]
                mealIndex?.let { index ->
                    val day = StorageDayUtils.returnDay(StorageDayUtils.currentDate, context)
                    day?.let {
                        if (index >= 0 && index < day.meals.size) {
                            val newWeight = editTextWeightFood.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: product.servingSizeNumber.toDouble()
                            val weightRatio = newWeight / 100

                            val updatedProduct = updateToAdd(product, weightRatio, newWeight)

                            day.meals[index].products.add(updatedProduct)
                            StorageDayUtils.saveDay(day, context, false)
                            FragmentUtils.closeBottomSheet()

                            // Obtener el nombre de la comida seleccionada
                            val mealName = foodNamesList.find { it.mealVariable == mealVar }?.foodName ?: "Comida Desconocida"

                            val message = context.getString(R.string.product_registered) + " " + mealName + "."
                            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.product_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

En este boton, actualizo el alimento si es que existe en la comida seleccionada, caso contrario, la agrego

```
bttUpdateFood.setOnClickListener {
            val selectedMeal = FunctionsDay.getSelectedMeals()
            selectedMeal.let { mealVar ->
                val mealIndex = Meal.mealNamesMap[mealVar]
                mealIndex?.let { index ->
                    val day = StorageDayUtils.returnDay(StorageDayUtils.currentDate, context)
                    day?.let {
                        if (index >= 0 && index < day.meals.size) {
                            val newWeight = editTextWeightFood.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: product.servingSizeNumber.toDouble()
                            val weightRatio = newWeight / 100

                            val updatedProduct = updateToAdd(product, weightRatio, newWeight)

                            val existingProductIndex = day.meals.get(index).products.indexOfFirst { it.name == updatedProduct.name }
                            if (existingProductIndex >= 0) {
                                day.meals[index].products[existingProductIndex] = updatedProduct
                            } else {
                                day.meals.get(index).products.add(updatedProduct)
                            }

                            StorageDayUtils.saveDay(day, context, true)
                            DiaryFragment.instance?.adapterForRecycler(day.meals[index], index)
                            FragmentUtils.closeBottomSheet()

                            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.product_updated), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.product_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Dentro de la función de cargar dia (la cual se llama siempre que guardo el dia, y que el sobreargumento de saveDay() sea true), llamo a funcion una llamada updateListView(), en la cual a un array de Recycler View les asigno un adaptador personalizado, pasandoles como argumento la lista de productos de todos los dias, cada Recycler View deberia tener su dia correspondiente segun el index

```
fun updateListView(day: Day) {
        day.meals.forEachIndexed { index, meal ->
            val recyclerView = recyclerView_Meals[index]
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.context)
        val adapter = recyclerView.let {
            DiaryListAdapter(it.context, meal.products) { product ->
                FunctionsDay.onItemRecyclerClick(product)
            }
        }

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.attachSwipeToDelete(recyclerView, meal.products)
        }
    }
```

Ahora, en adaptador personalizado tengo una función en la cual puedo deslizar un producto a la izquierda, y este debería eliminarse

```
fun attachSwipeToDelete(recyclerView: RecyclerView, productList: MutableList<Product>) {
        val swipeThreshold = 0.15f // Porcentaje de deslizamiento para mostrar el icono
        val mBackground: ColorDrawable = ColorDrawable()
        val mClearPaint: Paint = Paint()
        val backgroundColor: Int = Color.parseColor("#b80f0a")
        val deleteDrawable: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.delete_icon)
        val intrinsicWidth: Int = deleteDrawable?.intrinsicWidth ?: 0
        val intrinsicHeight: Int = deleteDrawable?.intrinsicHeight ?: 0

        val swipeHandler = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val product = productList.removeAt(position)
                recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRemoved(position)
                saveDayAfterDeletion(product)
            }

            override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

                val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
                val itemHeight = itemView.height

                val isCancelled = dX == 0f && !isCurrentlyActive

                if (isCancelled) {
                    clearCanvas(c, itemView.right + dX, itemView.top.toFloat(), itemView.right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat())
                    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                    return
                }

                mBackground.color = backgroundColor
                mBackground.setBounds(itemView.right + dX.toInt(), itemView.top, itemView.right, itemView.bottom)
                mBackground.draw(c)

                val deleteIconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
                val deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
                val deleteIconLeft = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin - intrinsicWidth
                val deleteIconRight = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin
                val deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeight

                // Verifica si el desplazamiento supera el umbral para mostrar el icono
                if (dX.absoluteValue >= itemView.width * swipeThreshold) {
                    deleteDrawable?.setTint(Color.WHITE) // Cambia el color del icono a blanco
                    deleteDrawable?.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom)
                    deleteDrawable?.draw(c)
                }

                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
            }

            private fun clearCanvas(c: Canvas, left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
                c.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mClearPaint)
            }
        }
        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeHandler)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }
```

Aqui es donde describo el problema, ya que si es que agrego un alimento a cualquier comida o uno ya existente lo actualizo pero sin cambiar sus datos y lo intento borrar funciona, el dia se guarda, se carga y se actualizan los list view, pero si agrego un alimento, lo actualizo cambiando sus datos, o lo agrego a otra comida, y lo intento borrar este no se borra, y recibire este error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.snowdev.growU, PID: 23057
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:511)
    at com.snowdev.growU.Adapter.DiaryListAdapter$attachSwipeToDelete$swipeHandler$1.onSwiped(DiaryListAdapter.kt:89)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper$4.run(ItemTouchHelper.java:712)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```